# angularfirebase2 set/update keeps adding zero's. Normal?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-realtime-database

So I'm figuring out Firebase with Angular4 + AngularFirebase2. I'm pretty successful so far with getting and setting values, but it keeps adding zeros. Here's my data.service:

```
addReading(readings, uid){
    this.af.list('/accounts').set(uid, readings)
  }
```

Here's the component's function:

```
postit(){
   this.myarray=[
     {
       pet:'pooch2'
     }
   ]

   this.myvar = this.ds.addReading(this.myarray, this.uid)
  }
```

This is what I'm getting in the JSON view of the Firebase database:

[image]

Everytime I add a new record, it keeps adding zeros. Is that normal?

Comment: Are you trying to add an array of pets, or just the one per account?  If the former, that seems to be working as I'd expect.  If the latter, you want to use `object` instead of `list`.

Comment: It's the former, I'm able to add a full array of things, it's just that zero under the account ID number that confused me. I guess it'll be left there? In general under "zero" it would be like Pet: dog, name: dog_name, age:5

Comment: That's just how it stores the index when you set an array.  If you had two pets, the second would be under 1.

Comment: Figured it out. Submitting as array will make it count from 0 and moving forward. Whereas submitting as object submits without those zeros.

Comment: The Firebase Database natively stored arrays in the format you see. For more, read: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html